# Unable to create a table in new database

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

beginner at SQL here, specifically using PostgreSQL. I'm trying to do something for a class here, but I keep receiving an error message and I'm not sure why. I've created a new database called "games", and I'm trying to create a basic table.  The code is below.

The error message I receive is, [0A000] ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "games.games_schema.player_data" Position: 14

I can make the table in the default DB with postgreSQL fine, but why am I having issues trying to specifically create this table within this new Database?

CREATE DATABASE games;

CREATE TABLE games.games_schema.Player_Data
(Player_ID int,
Player_Name VARCHAR(255),
Player_System VARCHAR(255));

I thought the way I have my create table statement set up, is telling the server to create a table at that location. (database --> DBschema --> table)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the games database, but that does not create a games_schema within it. It'll only create the schema Public (unless the default template has been modified)  The solution is to either create a "games_schema" in the "games" database, or create your DB objects in the public schema.
Option 1: Create a schema.

```
create schema games_schema; 
create table games_schema.player_data( ... );
```

Option 2: Use the Public schema.

```
create table player_data( ... );
```

My choice would be option 1, as I never allow anything other than extensions and Postgres supplied objects in public.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the response, I was able to do this by right clicking on the db and schema's in the side window, however when i tried to execute the code it would not let me create the schema. I tried typing in create schema games.games_schema; and it would not execute saying there was a syntax error. I'm just wondering why i have to right click and use a interface to build the table within the database instead of just being able to right the statement out.

Comment: if i typed create schema games_schema; it would default to putting the schema under the default postgres db.

Comment: Yes. Create schema will create the specified schema within the database you signed into.

Comment: I'm an idiot guys, it's because I didn't have a new console associated with that particular database, i was using the console associated with the public db. Thanks all for support.